# SQL Server Remove Last Word

Tags: sql-server

I have variables in a column named Tier. Please see below some examples;

```
Tier  
Tier 1 (Unspecified)
Tier 7 (Anti-client)
Tier 3 (Priority)
```

I would like the variables to be transformed like the below;

```
Tier  
Tier 1
Tier 7
Tier 3
```

Would you know how to efficiently remove all the strings in brackets at the end of the variables?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Please visit and read this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show sample data, show the code you wrote, and tell us what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
create table #table1 
    (id int
    ,Tier varchar(100)
    )

insert into #table1 VALUES
(1, 'Tier 1 (Unspecified)'),
(2, 'Tier 7 (Anti-client)'),
(3, 'Tier 3 (Priority)')

select  id,
        substring(tier, 1, charindex('(', tier) - 1) as Tier
from    #table1
```

You can use `substring(tier, 1, charindex('(', tier) - 2) as Tier` if you are sure that there's a space before the bracket